# Blog post bypassing workflow in Kentico

Tags: kentico

I have a situation where blog posts when saved are being instantly available on the site despite:

- Having workflow applied that has a specific "publish" step
- The repeaters on the blog page having "show published" ticked

This only seems to be affecting blog post pages, other pages behave as expected.

Any suggestions?  Kentico 9 EMS

Comment: What is the workflow setup? Is it set to automatically publish changes? What workflow is applied to the bog posts - check some post -> Properties -> Workflow tab

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the Workflow general setup has "automatically publish changes" checked by mistake.

[image]

Also, double check to see if the Blog section is covered by multiple workflow scope or not. Check the Workflow tab of a blog post and see which workflow is actually been enforced.

Answer (score 0):

This was a self induced problem.

We found a global event handler that was being used to set some default properties on page creation, in which was a checkout and checkin.  Looks like the checkout/checkin was publishing the page and then setting it back to edit mode.

Resolved by removing the checkout/checkin from the code.